# Making multipoint column with at least 2 points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, multipoint

I have a table called `my_table` that has a MultiPoint column. I want to limit the MultiPoint column.
A Multipoint must have 3 Points most and it must have 2 points at least.

How can I do the limitation ?

```sql
-- this is my table
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id serial Primary Key,
  geom geometry(MultiPointZ, 4326)
)
```

This one should work, because it has 2 points.

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (geom)
VALUES (
    ST_SETSRID(ST_Collect(
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 0),
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 0)
    ), 4326)
)
```

This one should **NOT** work, because it has a point.

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (geom)
VALUES (
    ST_SETSRID(ST_Collect(
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 0)
    ), 4326)
)
```

This one should **NOT** work, because it has 4 points.

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (geom)
VALUES (
    ST_SETSRID(ST_Collect(
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 0),
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 0),
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 0),
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 0)
    ), 4326)
)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to limit geom column.  A Multipoint must have 3 Points most. A Multipoint must have 2 points at least.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a question mark that indicates the question that you are asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id   GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  geom GEOMETRY(MULTIPOINTZ, 4326),

  CHECK (ST_NumGeometries(geom) BETWEEN 2 AND 3)
);
```

`ST_NumGeometries` behaves `IMMUTABLE` and should be supported. You *may* need to explicitly use `>=` and `<=` rather than `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need handle this by first converting it into string and substring formatting
try by using check constraint
refer this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699685/17549908